# difference between device id and pnp device id

Tags: windows, device, device-driver, hardware-interface

can somebody please explain difference between those two terms, when I'm trying to print

structs from `Win32_AllocatedResource()` I can find `pnp device id` (something like  `PCI\\VEN_...`)
and when I'm trying to print structs from `Win32_IDEControllerDevice()` I can find `device id` (something like `IDE\\CDROM...`)

but what is the difference `why do I need both of them`? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Win32_AllocatedResource gives you the assignment of a given resource (e.g. a DMA starting address) to some "device" (or "object"), which when ResultClass = Win32_IDEController, is the *controller*.

Win32_IDEControllerDevice gives you the list of "devices" (or "object") that are connected to a certain controller, the Antecedent key is the DeviceID of the *controller* whereas the Dependent key is the DeviceID of the *storage unit*.